# How to add new key in json flow by nifi jolt processor

Tags: apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

how to convert the following data

```json
{
  "name" : "abcd",
  "middleName" : "srivastav"
}
```

into

```json
{
  "name" : "abcd",
  "middleName" : "srivastav"
  "id" : "abcd"
}
```

by using a jolt transform such that the `id` and the `name` are within the same object as the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

**modify-default-beta** or **default** operations will work for this :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "id": "abcd"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to replicate the value of `name` through use of **`"@(0,name)":`** while keeping the current attributes by `"*": "&"` notation within a **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "@(0,name)": "id"
    }
  }
]
```

the **demo** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is
[image]

or another option is to use a modify(overwrite/default) transformation to dynamically replicate the value of `name` attribute for `id` such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "id": "@(1,name)"
    }
  }
]
```

the second **demo** is

[image]